# checking network reachability in real time

Tags: ios, reachability

When the user presses a button, I need to know whether the device is connected to the internet at that very instant--not whether he was connected 3 seconds ago. The reachability (tonymillion) notifier takes about that long to update after there is a change in network reachability.

I thought that I would be able to check for actual access in real time using the following methods:

```
if (!([[Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"] currentReachabilityStatus] == NotReachable)) NSLog(@"reachable");
if ([[Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"] currentReachabilityStatus] == NotReachable) NSLog(@"not reachable");
```

But results indicated that in fact `currentReachabilityStatus` does not check for internet access; it only checks the same flag that is updated with ~3 seconds' delay.

What's an efficient way of actually checking for network access on the spot?

Comment: You can send a header request to google.com using NSURLRequest. That should be pretty fast.

Comment: Unless Google.com is down.

Comment: @HAS That sounds good, but I'm not sure how to create a header request. If you put some code in answer, I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: If three seconds is an unacceptable delay, how long is acceptable?

Comment: @CarlVeazey The issue is not the length of the delay; it's that the status is not updated in real time. I have an if/then statement, and I need to go down one path only if there's an internet connection---at present, not 3 seconds ago.

Comment: In other words, some delay while I ascertain conditions is fine, but relying on conditions from a moment ago could lead to undesirable results. Someone out there must know how to construct a simple ping or header request.

Comment: A HEAD request is easy to do, but it won't truly solve this problem. Imagine if one of your users' cellular providers puts hard caps on their bandwidth, and they have enough bandwidth to make and receive the HEAD request, but then halfway through receiving the real response the app needs to do work, their provider cuts them off. My point being, networking is inherently asynchronous and unreliable, and programs should be coded in a way that makes living with these facts easier. If you provide additional details I may be able to give more specific suggestions as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wished in the comments above here is a solution using a "HEAD" request.

1. Make your class conforming to the
   [NSURLConnectionDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLConnectionDelegate).
2. Implement the `connection:didReceiveResponse:` delegate method
3. Optionally implement the `connection:didFailWithError:` delegate method

So your setup could look like this:

YourClass.m

```
@interface YourClass () <NSURLConnectionDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURLConnection *headerConnection;
@end

@implementation YourClass

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // You can do this in whatever method you want
    NSMutableURLRequest *headerRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:10.0];
    headerRequest.HTTPMethod = @"HEAD";
    self.headerConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:headerRequest delegate:self];
}

#pragma mark - NSURLConnectionDelegate Methods

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    if (connection == self.headerConnection) {
        // Handle the case that you have Internet; if you receive a response you are definitely connected to the Internet
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // Note: Check the error using `error.localizedDescription` for getting the reason of failing
    NSLog(@"Failed: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting an observer on the reachability status?

The Reachabilty extension ([NPReachability](https://github.com/Abizern/NPReachability)) that I used to use, allows KVO on the status.